# Ingress Gateway/Virutal Service not working with Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, kubernetes, akka-http, minikube, istio

I' running an application with an Akka HTTP endpoint on minikube. The application is running and I can access it if I use the port forward command: `kubectl -n innfactory-demo port-forward PODNAMEFORSERVICE2 8090:8090`
Istio is also installed and running on minikube. I would now like to create an gateway and a virtual service so that I don't need the port forward anymore. Unfortunately that's not working.

Versions:

- Debian 10
- Minikube 1.2.0
- Istio 1.2.4
- Scala 2.13.0

Pods running in the namesapce innfactory-demo

I've already deployed the [httpbin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.2/samples/httpbin/httpbin.yaml) example in the innfactory-demo namespace and created the gateway and virtual service like in the [Istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/). If I do it like in this example I can access the httpbin service from outside.

If I'm adapting the httpbin example to my [service](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Michael-List/akka-microservice-sample/istio/k8s/service2.yaml) and deploy this [gateway and virtual service](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Michael-List/akka-microservice-sample/istio/k8s/istio-gateway.yaml). I cannot access my service from the outside.
I've tried various configurations but none seems to work. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: you need to do `minikube ssh` and configure the domain in your hosts file or pass host header in the url `curl --verbose --header 'Host: www.example.com' 'http://10.1.1.36:8000/the_url_to_test'`

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi I'm getting the error ```connectionn refused``` on port 8000 and on the ingress port(31380). I already tried adding the header.
```curl --verbose -HHost:demo.example.com http://192.168.99.102:8000/greet/Test```
and
```curl --verbose -HHost:demo.example.com http://192.168.99.102:31380/greet/Test```

Comment: Could you please try with port 80? `curl --verbose -HHost:demo.example.com http://192.168.99.102/greet/Test`

Comment: Sadly the same error with ```connection refused``` occurs

Comment: Let's take the discussion over to https://discuss.istio.io or slack https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfdsupDfOWBtNVvVvXED6ULxtR4UIsYGCH_cQcRr0VcG1ZqQQ/viewform

Comment: I could finally fix it. It was a wrong port at the gateway settings: https://github.com/Michael-List/akka-microservice-sample/commit/4a13de50d1717b63ae7f4fc974a27bb7a948da36
I was looking at it a thousand times but couldn't spot it.
Thank you for your help!